# WCF Underlying Connection Error while returning DataTable

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, datatable

I created the webservices method that returns a dataTable.
However, I am getting the error:

> The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

This is my method in the IWS file

```
[ServiceContract]
 public interface IWsBabyCare
 {
    [OperationContract]
    DataTable GetPurchaseOrderDetails();

    [OperationContract]
    DataTable GetPurchaseOrders(int PODID);

  }
```

And this is my method in the WS file

```
public DataTable GetPurchaseOrderDetails()
{
    DataTable POD = new DataTable("POD");
    PurchaseOrderBLL prodBLL = new PurchaseOrderBLL();
    POD = prodBLL.GetPOD();
    POD.TableName = "POD";
    return POD;

}

public DataTable GetPurchaseOrders(int PODID)
{
    PurchaseOrderBLL prodBLL = new PurchaseOrderBLL();
    return prodBLL.GetPurchaseOrders(PODID);
}
```

I read online that adding a name to the datatable will help but I'll just be returning an empty dataTable.

Comment: where's the code for your data access  (the .Get's)?   What have you done to troubleshoot the connection?

Comment: You should not be returning types of DataTable from your service operations. See here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReturningDataSetsFromWebServicesIsTheSpawnOfSatanAndRepresentsAllThatIsTrulyEvilInTheWorld.aspx

Comment: Did you find out the problem in the end?

Answer (score 0):

The exception you are getting can have about [500 different causes](http://bit.ly/YSSEAu).

All we can really tell at the moment is that you have a service interface defining some operations and that your have implemented the operations.

We know nothing about the way the service is being hosted (console, IIS?), or the WCF configuration specified on the service and client. You need to supply this information in your question.

Additionally your service operations specify a return type of `DataTable` which is a [big](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReturningDataSetsFromWebServicesIsTheSpawnOfSatanAndRepresentsAllThatIsTrulyEvilInTheWorld.aspx) web service no-no. You should be passing types which define exactly the data you need (for example, if your database table contain apples, you should pass a return type of `List<Apple>`.

This is how I suggest you should proceed.

1. Create a console-based service and client project.
2. Create a single service operation which returns some primitive type like string.
3. Make all code as simple as possible. You should be able to get this working with less than 10 lines of code and about 10 lines of xml config on each of the service and client.
4. Once you have managed to get this working then gradually add new operations and more complex return types.